# Optimality condition of proximal gradient

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, proximal-operators

Given a convex $L$-smooth function $g: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a differentiable convex function $h: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I want to find the optimality condition of the following algorithm
$$x_k = \arg \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \frac{L}{2} \|x - x_{k-1}\|^2 + \nabla g^T(x_{k-1})(x - x_{k-1}) + h(x)$$

I've just differentiated the function and got the following condition
$$x_k = x_{k-1} - \frac{1}{L}[\nabla g^T(x_{k-1}) + \nabla h(x_k)]$$

**My question**  Is it possible to have $x_k$ on one side and $\nabla h(x_k)$ at the other one? Is there a way to get an explicit condition for $x_k$?

Comment: Use the definition of the proximal map. Depending on available definitions you can also complete the square in the argmin and use the definition of the prox directly without taking a derivative.

Comment: @Dirk , Thank you! Could you please make some more explanations, maybe as an answer, I'd appreciate that!